# sum of product of bessel functions with constant difference in index

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

While doing a calculation on frequency modulation I am encountering the sum
$$
\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} J_{n+m}(z)J_m(z)
$$
which looks awfully similar to the identity:
$$
J_n(t+r) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} J_k(t) J_{n-k}(r)
$$
Except the former sum is over indices with fixed difference, while the latter is with fixed sum.

For the case of $n=0$, I see my expression has the simplification
$$
J_0^2(z) + 2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}J_m^2(z)=1
$$
Does a simplification exist for $n\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a bit more searching I have found on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23):
$$
\mathscr{C}_{\nu}\left(u\pm v\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathscr{C}_{\nu%
\mp k}\left(u\right)J_{k}\left(v\right)
$$
Where $\mathscr{C}_{\nu}$ is a "cylinder function". The Bessel functions $J_v$ are cylinder functions, so taking the bottom row of the $\pm$ we get:
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\nu
+ k}\left(z\right)J_{k}\left(z\right) = J_\nu(z-z) = J_\nu(0)=\delta_{\nu 0}
$$
Which is what I had been finding to be the case numerically.